# Rhythmn part of solo guitar arrangements

Tags: guitar, acoustic-guitar, rhythm, arranging

I have read some tips on solo guitar arrangement that suggest to find melody part, then bass part, then fill in the middle of those 2 parts. I can manage the melody and bass part, but I have no idea for the middle? 
How do people arrange it? 
Is there anything that I can use as a base idea to create that part?
I meant about how to choose notes, and make it more interesting.

Comment: Many of the 19th century classical guitar pieces are built this way.  The middle is often a repeated open string arpeggio.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I am missing the mark on this one, but a tool I use a lot is to:

1. Put the melody on one of the upper 2 strings (B,E)
2. Put the bass on one of the lower 2 strings (E, A)
3. Put the guide tones on the middle 2 strings (3rds and 7ths on D, G)

Since you were just looking for a base idea, this might be all you needed, or as I said, I may be way off the mark on what you are asking!

Hope it helps!

Steve

Comment: Oh, what I meant was how to choose notes for the guide tones, the idea to make it more interesting, since I tried to arrange some songs before, but I played the melody basically on top of chord patterns, so the middle sticks with the chord and I found it quite cliché. I want to get somehow more creative.
Sorry, I should have made the question clearer :")

Comment: Generally speaking "Guide Tones" are the tones in the chord that make up it's quality. Specifically the 3rd interval and the 7th interval. IE: Am7 would be a C (m3) and G (m7) note. So not much of a choice. Now let's say you only play those 2 notes, and instead of an A in the base, you play a B. No you have the notes C, G and B playing under your melody which imply maybe a Cmaj7 (no 3rd), etc. Honestly I am finding it a bit hard to explain what my head seems to be doing on it's own! I can expand more, but am not even sure I am being helpful!